# Acesso a subpastas na URL está sendo bloqueado pelo .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, url, request

Olá, tenho uma url dem um sistema no qual upei um **"ambiente_teste"** em uma subpasta dentro do diretorio do sistema.

O *.htaccess* direciona o index para um arquivo **"app.php"** qual é o arquivo que faz o autoload do sistema.

O direcionamento dele, na pasta **"http://meusite.com.br/ambiente_testes/web"** está com o *.htaccess* assim:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     #Habilita o Módulo de Reescrita
     RewriteEngine On

     #Define a pasta da raiz
     RewriteBase /ambiente_testes/web/

     #Se a URL apontar para um arquivo, vai diretamente para ele
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

     #Regras de redirecionamento
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Ao entrar no **"http://meusite.com.br/ambiente_testes/web"** ele não redireciona para o **app.php**, e retorna um erro 302, no chrome ele redireciona automaticamente apos o erro 302 para um erro 404 e assim redireciona a request para **"http://meusite.com.br/pagina-nao-encontrada"**

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso estar resolvendo isto?